# Error parsing configuration/hibernate.cfg.xml?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

### My XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
   "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
   "http://www.hibernate.sourceforge.net/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">


<hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>
       <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>

       <property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.252.128:1521:orcl</property>

       <property name="connection.username">system</property>

       <property name="connection.passowrd">manager</property>

       <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>

       <property name="show_sql">true</property>

       <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

       <mapping class="com.nttdata.domain.Employee"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

---

Console after execution ::

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: problem parsing configuration/hibernate.cfg.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1222)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1161)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1147)
    at com.nttdata.util.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:11)
    at com.nttdata.dao.EmployeeDao.saveEmployee(EmployeeDao.java:13)
    at com.nttdata.client.Driver.main(Driver.java:10)
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: www.hibernate.sourceforge.net Nested exception: www.hibernate.sourceforge.net
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1217)
    ... 5 more
```

---

What can be the error any help??

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the DOCTYPE to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
    "classpath://org/hibernate/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

This means that hibernate will load the DTD from classpath - it is usually included in hibernate jar in org/hibernate directory.

However, we use hibernate 3.5.6 - I don't hnow if this approach still works in the newer version - give it a try. The benefit of this is that you are completely independent on internet connection, proxies and so on.

**Hibernate Configuration File Location**

The first solution was to provide the DTD file location in the system using classpath. So the DocType that worked offline would be;

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
    "classpath://org/hibernate/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

**Use SourceForge DTD URL with SYSTEM**

Another solution I found working is when I change the DTD URL to SourceForge and changed the declaration from PUBLIC to SYSTEM.

So below will also work if your system is offline.

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```